# Gnuplot: imposing bounds on fitting parameters

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

Is there a way to contraint the values that fitting parameters can take with gnuplot?

```
f(x) = A/(x**2) + B/(x**4)
A = 1
B = 0.01
fit f(x) 'data.dat' u 1:2 via A,B
```

I know that `B < 0` doesn't make any sense. Is there a way to impose `B > 0`?

Answer (score 2):

Since gnuplot supports non-linear fitting you can use `B**2` (or `sqrt(B**2)`) in your function to constrain your variable to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your function to something like this:

```
minB = 0.001
f(x) = A*x**-2 + (B<minB:minB:B)*x**-4
```

But i'm not sure how the NLLS alogrithm reacts to this. Beware.

Or you might think about something like this:

```
f(x) = A*x**-2 + 10**B*x**-4
```

Probably this will react much smoother and be closer to an actual physical model of your data.